# How to get the value of a key in python dictionary

Tags: python

I have this `python` output that retrieves a dictionary like below. I want to get the value of `TopicArn` that falls inside `NotificationConfiguration`.

This is my output looks like.

output of `clusters`

```
{
    'Marker': 'string',
    'CacheClusters': [
        {
            'CacheClusterId': 'string',
            'ConfigurationEndpoint': {
                'Address': 'string',
                'Port': 123
            },
            'ClientDownloadLandingPage': 'string',,
            'PendingModifiedValues': {
                'NumCacheNodes': 123,
                'CacheNodeIdsToRemove': [
                    'string',
                ],
                'EngineVersion': 'string',
                'CacheNodeType': 'string',
                'AuthTokenStatus': 'SETTING'|'ROTATING'
            },
            'NotificationConfiguration': {
                'TopicArn': 'string',
                'TopicStatus': 'string'
            },        
            'ReplicationGroupId': 'string',
        },
    ]
}
```

This is what I tried:

```
def get_ec_cache_Arn(region, clusters):
    ec_client = boto3.client('elasticache', region_name=region)

    count = 1

    for cluster in clusters['CacheClusters']:
        cluster_arn = cluster['NotificationConfiguration'][0]['TopicArn']
```

But this doesn't work. gives no output. But `clusters` has a value I am passing from some other function. When I print `clusters` it produces the above-mentiond dictionary. That means `clusters` is not empty.

Can someone help me?

Comment: There's nothing in the code fragment you posted that's even capable of producing any output, so it's not very clear what you're asking here.

Comment: Your code should actually raise a `KeyError`, so please edit your question with a PROPER [mcve] and the full matching traceback.  Also note that python has a very comprehe,sive tutorial, a full documentation, an interactive shell and a step debugger, so use all those features before posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your `for` loop. You've put `[0]` there which will throw `KeyError` because in python dictionaries are not ordered and you can't use indexing with them.

```
for cluster in clusters['CacheClusters']:
        cluster_arn = cluster['NotificationConfiguration']['TopicArn']
```

This gives desired output.

Answer (score 1):

```
   for cluster in clusters['CacheClusters']:
        cluster_arn = cluster['NotificationConfiguration']['TopicArn']
```

You have an excessive `[0]` in your code. You've tried to acces element `0`, but 'NotificationConfiguration' is a dictionary and not a list.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share a general method to access dictionary elements:

```
for key, value in clusters.items():
  assert clusters[key] == value, "access the value according to the key".
```